# Can you filter by Dialogflow agent environment in Stackdriver?

Tags: dialogflow-es, stackdriver

We are looking into using the version and environments feature in Dialogflow that is no longer in beta. We currently have different agents for dev, testing and production, but we are researching whether it would be better to use different environments within a single agent instead.

One concern I have is whether the different environments would all be piled together in the logs in Stackdriver? I can't find any information on this. Is it possible to search Stackdriver per environment?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by ""Environments"". 
Are the dev, test, and production in 3 different projects? Stackdriver Logging works 
on a per project basis by default. If all the ""environments"" are in the same project, 
then the logs will all be sent to Logging within that single project.

Comment: @Mahboob I'm talking about the new Versions and Environments feature in Dialogflow. (If we choose to use this feature) dev, test and production would all be in the same project/agent, but in different environments made using the Versions and Environments feature.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your inquiry and I am able to find logs in Stackdriver logging for each environment.

- First I have enabled Log Interactions to Google Cloud in the agent General settings in the Dialogflow Console.
- Second I have created different environments and I made calls to them following the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-versions#test_your_agent_in_an_environment).

Then, the logs that make reference to those environments include the environment name.
So, if you set an advanced filter like:

```
resource.type="audited_resource"
resource.labels.service="dialogflow.googleapis.com"
"<your-environment-name>"
```

in Stackdriver logging, you will be able to find the interactions with that environment and just that one.

I have checked both succeeding requests and failed ones and all of them can be filtered with the previous advanced filter. Furthermore, in the case of failed requests the error/s show in the logs which is great for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks. It seems the Dialogflow team recently added the environment name, because when I contacted them they said it wasn't possible to search per environment and they would work on that feature.